How do I pluck the Winged Pikmin on Below-Grade Discotheque Sublevel 3?
On the map Serene Shores, there is a cave called Below-Grade Discotheque. The third sublevel has a raised platform with a Pink Pikmin bud. I threw some yellow Pikmin up their to turn them into Winged Pikmin, but I can't find a way to get up there and pluck them.
How do I pluck the Winged Pikmin on Below-Grade Discotheque Sublevel 3?


The higher-angle shot might give you the hint you need. Also notice there is a dog in the picture.


 Jump from the pushed cardboard box to the Bouncy Mushroom. You'll get sent into a fan that will launch you up to the rose Candypop Bud.
 

(image source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpy2r2EJPEQ&t=6h15m21s)
